# How to addTarget with more properties?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

one simple question cause I couldn't find quickly any special answer for my issue.

I have such a method:

```
- (void)changeValueForEasy:(UISlider *)slider offset:(int)offset {}
```

And I'm trying to call it with event, but I don't know how to add an additional object like "offset" to this:

```
[blueSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(changeValueForEasy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

```
    [blueSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDragged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

then

```
- (void)sliderDragged:(UISlider *)slider;
{
    [self changeValueForEasy:slider offset:slider.value];
}
```

The method name suggests that it sets the slider's value, the fact that you want to call this method suggests that you do some extra processing when the value is changed. I would recommend abstracting the additional processing out into another method or the slider's value will be being set twice.

Comment: It works, but doesn't simplify my code... I need to define the 'offset' there, where I call action...

Comment: I don't know what happens inside of `changeValueForEasy:offset:` so I can't say if there is a better way. Can you show the implementation?